# Failed to register a ServiceWorker when PUBLIC_URL is CDN in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, create-react-app, cdn

react-scripts: v3.2.0

I want to load my react web application from cdn using service worker and set PUBLIC_URL to my CDN url at build time.

As in [this link](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration) describe about PUBLIC_URL, It is usefull for hosting app in CDN.

[image]

But it's not work for me and service worker doesn't enable in production.
Should I set homepage in package.json to my CDN url? Or it's irrelevant?